# SLQAlchemy can't create relational column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Thanks in advance. I'm working on the application in Flask + SQLAlchemy. At first, I initialized database `flask db init`.

```
$ flask db init

  Creating directory /Users/xxxx/app/migrations ...  done
  Creating directory /Users/xxxx/app/migrations/versions ...  done
  Generating /Users/xxxx/app/migrations/script.py.mako ...  done
  Generating /Users/xxxx/app/migrations/env.py ...  done
  Generating /Users/xxxx/app/migrations/README ...  done
  Generating /Users/xxxx/app/migrations/alembic.ini ...  done
  Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/Users/xxxx/app/migrations/alembic.ini'
  before proceeding.
```

And then I have run `flask db migrate`. But it occurred an error that SQLAlchemy can't create a relational column.

> Foreign key associated with column 'post.user_id' could not find table 'user' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

My code:

**app/__init__.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app.config')

# migrate db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app.db import (
    User, Post
)

def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
```

**app/config.py**

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///develop.db'
SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**app/db.py**

```py
from app import db

# Model
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String)
    uid = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    token = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.uid

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by modifying:

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

by

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Comment: Hmm, I got a same error. `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'post.user_id' could not find table 'User' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

Comment: @ShunYamada: Modified my answer. try with data from __tablename__.

Answer (score 1):

The disagreement that SQLAlchemy is reporting is between

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
```

and

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Choose one of "users" or "users"

Comment: I have remove ` __tablename__ = 'users'` instead. But it is not working.

Comment: By default, SQAlchemy will pluralize the class name to form the table name. You can override that by `__tablename__ = 'user'`, or you can user `users.id`.